# Please help me to fix the error in this menu code

Tags: html, css

I have learnt CSS online and I am new to web designing. Need some expert opinion here, I may have written something wrong or stupid. Please forgive that as I am a beginner.

Here are my CSS and HTML codes:

```css
    #menu {
     float: left;
     width: 1000px;
     height: 30px;
     background-color:#0066FF;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #333;``
    }
    
    #menu ul {
     float: left;
     width: 1000px;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 7px 0 0 0;
     list-style: none;
    }
    
    #menu ul li{
     display:inline;
    }
    li ul {display: none;}
    li:hover ul {display: block; position:relative;}
    li:hover li a{background: #0066FF;}
    #menu ul li a{
     float: left;
     padding: 0 20px;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    #menu li a:hover, #menu li .current{
     color: #FFFF00;
    }
    
    #menu ul li:hover ul{
        width: 150px;
     white-space: nowrap
     height: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     background:#0066FF;
     }
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html"  class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quran</a>
      
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Translation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tajweed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tafseer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Qoutes</a></li>
      
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ahadees</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sahih Al-Bukhari</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sahih Muslim</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Sunan Abu-Dawud</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">al-Tirmidhi</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">al-Nasa'i</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ibn Maja </a></li>
      </ul></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wazaif</a>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Allah's help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rizzaq</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Aulaad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marriage</a></li>
      
      </ul></li>  
        <li><a href="#">Rights & Duties</a>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">As Parents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">As Husband</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">As Wife</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">As Son</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">As Daughter</a></li>
     
      </ul></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Molana Tariq Jameel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dr Zakir Naik</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dr Farhat Hashmi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Naat videos</a></li>
      
      </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quran & Science</a></li>                     
      
        <li><a href="#">Library</a>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Masnoon Duain</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tib-e-Nabvi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tafseer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Islamic comerace</a></li>
      </ul></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>            
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: 1.The drop down menu appear and disturb the whole menu list when hover.                                                                                                                                           2. When the sub menu is shown it does not appear exactly under its parent.

Comment: I've created a code snippet to contain your code, but you need to update your question as to what specific behavior you are trying to achieve with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you haven't positioned the sub-menus properly.

Because the sub-menu have not been given `position:absolute` they remain in the documents flow and so disturb other elements when shown.

Adding `position:absolute` removes them from the flow and solves the problem.

In order to be positioned according to the parent `li`, that `li` needs to be a block (hence `display:inline-block`)(you could `float` the `li` too if that's your choice) and be given `position:relative`.

Here's a suggestion that should help you along the way.

```
#menu ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dkLx8bcd/)

```css
#menu {
  float: left;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #0066FF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  ``
}
#menu ul {
  float: left;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
li:hover li a {
  background: #0066FF;
}
#menu ul li a {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu li a:hover,
#menu li .current {
  color: #FFFF00;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
  width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0066FF;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Quran</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Translation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tajweed</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tafseer</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Qoutes</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Ahadees</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sahih Al-Bukhari</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sahih Muslim</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Sunan Abu-Dawud</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">al-Tirmidhi</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">al-Nasa'i</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Ibn Maja </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Wazaif</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Allah's help</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Rizzaq</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Aulaad</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Marriage</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Rights & Duties</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">As Parents</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">As Husband</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">As Wife</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">As Son</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">As Daughter</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Molana Tariq Jameel</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dr Zakir Naik</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dr Farhat Hashmi</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Naat videos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Quran & Science</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Library</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Masnoon Duain</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tib-e-Nabvi</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tafseer</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Islamic comerace</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blogs</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You did a great help to me indeed. No words to say thanks. stay blessed!

Comment: Thanks a lot! i hav added the revised CSS code to my page and the problem i was facing is gone for ever.... thanks again